# Settings to use Chrome with tor proxy?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am having a strange issue. I have used the below code for a while to launch a anonymous `wedriver` instance, however somehow my settings of Chrome have refreshed and now the traffic is not going through the `proxy`. I tried making changes to the code and the chrome options but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Also, it has somehow stopped adding the uBlock extension.

```
def anon_drive():
    os.startfile(r"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\tor-win32-0.2.9.9\Tor\tor.exe")
    time.sleep(10)
    chrome_path = r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'

    chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chop.add_extension(r'C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\Ublock\uBlock-Origin_v1.11.0.crx')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=chop)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    return driver
```

I have the Chrome options set to "Use a proxy server for your LAN is checked" I have tried setting the Advanced options to `127.0.0.1:9050` and `9051`.

Still getting

> Socks version 67 not recognised.(Tor is not an http proxy.)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. There are some answers which I found but I am unable to find one which would perfectly.

Comment: Set the proxy to be a socks proxy, not an http proxy. See for example [this](http://xme.im/how-use-socks-proxy-google-chrome) page.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I kept adding the ip and port to all options rather than just socks. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: Nah, you can answer your own question if you like.

Comment: Will do. Thanks. The number of complicated answers is just astounding.

Answer (score 0):

@JamesKPolk gave me the answer.

Steps:

Chrome>Settings>Advanced Settings>Open Proxy Settings> LAN Settings>Use a Proxy Server for LAN> Advanced> Socks: 127.0.0.1 Port 9050

Press OK and everything should work.

Note: Leave everything except Socks empty.